# How to add absolute path to all relative URLs in Puppeteer (local html file should load images from web to generate PDF)

Tags: pdf, url, path, reference, puppeteer

I have saved a single webpage to local disk (pure html-file, no changes).

When trying to create a PDF using Puppeteer, images with relative paths are missing. Also, all relative href links in the PDF reference to a local address that does not exist, instead of pointing to the correct addres on the webpage (which would be "http://www.example.com/" plus the relative URL)

Is it possible to define a prefix in Puppeteer that is added to all relative URLs (images, links, css, js), so "http://www.example.com/" is added to all relative URLs that start with "/" in the html file?

Answer (score 4):

This is possible to do using the [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element. From the docs:

> The **HTML `<base>` element** specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document. There can be only one `<base>` element in a document.

Be aware that this has to be specified before others elements with attributes that are URLs. That means it is not possible to execute some JavaScript to change the behavior of an already rendered page. Instead, you should change the HTML before rendering it.

Add the base element to your HTML code before rendering it so that it looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="http://www.example.com/">
...
```

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer is correct, it does not exactly shows how to inject the `base` tag automatically using puppeteer. I encountered the same issue, here is how to dynamically add a base tag in Puppeteer:

```
  await page.evaluate(() => {

    const base = document.createElement('base');
    base.href = window.location.origin;

    // Insert the base element as the first child of the head element
    document.head.insertBefore(base, document.head.firstChild);
  });
```